# How can I implement an http client in dart that works on mobile and web?

Tags: dart, cross-platform, dart-html, dart-http

I understand that I'm able to use [http::BrowserClient](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/browser_client/BrowserClient-class.html) for web and I'm able to use [http::Client](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client-class.html) for ios and android, but I can't use one library for both!

What is the standard implementation to have a http client that works on all 3 platforms?

Comment: Isn't `http::Client` supposed to work on all platforms already?  `http::Client` is already a common interface shared by `http::IOClient` (used by Android, iOS, etc.) and by `http::BrowserClient` (used for web), and [its factory constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/Client.html) "[creates] an `IOClient` if `dart:io` is available and a `BrowserClient` if `dart:html` is available".

Comment: It appears you are correct, should I delete my question?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Client() instead of using BrowserClient(). Client supports both io request and web requests so it will work on both desktop and web.
i.e:-

use --

```
import 'package:http/src/client.dart';
```

instead of --

```
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
```

and use

```
var client = Client();
```

instead of

```
var client = BrowserClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

**One can use https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io** which implements a client that's cross platform for mobile and web.

Cons: Small user base. Doesn't import io or http packages, at quick glance it looks like they copied the relevant files from those libraries, which would mean universal_io would be slow to get bugfixes.

**A second option** would be to write a wrapper for both BrowserClient and Client that would deliver the correct implementation depending on the platform using dart foundation.